# Not able to commit the transaction

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mule, mule-component, mule-esb

I have a requirement in which i have to catch erroneous data from a normal flow into a default-exception-strategy .For this within default-exception-strategy i have defined a spring mvc flow which captures this erroneous data and then it should save these data in oracle database.
But at present i am unable to save any records in db.
2 questions: 1)Am i using a correct exception strategy 2)if step one is not correct approach then what could be the best solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide your flow config

Comment: What is the relationship between the Mule application and the Spring MVC application?